# Predicting increasing income within a given time

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this game where player earns "gold" and "reputation". With higher reputation, the player nets more income (gold).

- Each reputation points yields 1% bonus in income (gold)
- For every 20 gold received, player receives 1 reputation points
- Player starts with receiving 10 gold every second. This increases as reputation point increases.

How much gold and reputation will the player receive after 1000 seconds?

So I'm asking for an equation/formula and how you came up with it. I tried simplifying the example so I can explain it easily. I think I need a quadratic equation of some sort, but i'm just speculating.

I'm not really that good with providing my own formula :(

EDIT:
Here's an excel simulation of what I described above: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vz5wizqg4x43599/offline%20progression%20simulation.xlsx?dl=0

The first row holds the initial value (Time = 0)

Comment: Is that $1000$ seconds?

Comment: Oh sorry about that. Yes it's 1000 seconds

Comment: Total Rep=Total Gold Recieved After n second / Gold Recieved for 1 reputation.                                                                                                        
Total income=Total Rep(20 gold+0.2 bonus)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0esrjusnrwki1r3/offline%20progression%20simulation%20%28Autosaved%29.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Let $G(n)$ be the gold after $n$ seconds and $R(n)$ the reputation after $n$ seconds.  Our system is $$G(n)=G(n-1)+(1+.01R(n-1))10\\R(n)=R(n-1)+G(n-1)/20\\R(0)=G(0)=0$$

Please check that these match your description.  In particular, the gain in rep comes one turn after receiving the gold and the gain in rate of gold comes one turn after the gain in rep as I have written it.  Also I didn't consider the gains indivisible-maybe you want floor functions around some things.

For small $n$, say up to a few thousand, it is easy to make a spreadsheet and calculate the values.  If you do it in a column, copy down is your friend.  I get $R(100)\approx 46264.3,\  G(100) \approx 65568.9,\  R(1000) \approx 6.549E31,\  G(1000) \approx 9.262E31$.  The long term growth rate for both is proportional to $1.070711^n$, which you can find by computing the eigenvalues of the matrix, or just dividing the values at time $n$ by those at time $n-1$

Added:  In your sheet, the rep is computed from current gold, not added, so the equations become $$G(n)=G(n-1)+(1+.01R(n-1))10\\R(n)=G(n-1)/20\\R(0)=G(0)=0$$  You actually round (it appears, though the function is called floor) $R$ to an integer.  That turns out not to make much difference.  Taking out the $R(n-1)$ from my earlier equations, we agree very closely.  Now we can write the second as $R(n-1)=G(n-2)/20$ and substitute into the first, getting $$G(n)=G(n-1)+10+G(n-2)/200$$  In the long run, $G(n)$ will increase as $1.005^n$, but we aren't there yet by 100 seconds.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=G%28n%29%3DG%28n-1%29%2B10%2BG%28n-2%29%2F200%2CG%280%29%3D0%2CG%281%29%3D10) gives values for the recurrence that verify my spreadsheet.  The $1.005$ comes from the larger root of the [characteristic equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%3Dx%2B1%2F200) $x^2=x+100$

Comment: I'm not sure how to convert this programatically. It seems that this function is recursive (at least from a programmer's perspective) since knowing G(n) requires evaluating G(n-1) until n is zero. Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding it.

I was able to do it in excel but not sure how you exactly put it. Can you tell me what you exactly copy pasted in the formula bar? Maybe I'll get an idea from it.

Thanks and sorry for being terrible at math XD

Comment: I've edited my question and included a simulation in excel sheet. Seems that we didn't match.

Comment: The largest discrepancy between our sheets is the presence of $R(n-1)$ on the right in my second line.  I awarded an additional rep of gold/20 each step, while you just gave a rep of gold/20.  You also took the floor when computing rep, while I did not.  This is why I asked you check that my equations were what was intended.  Your rep and gold should also increase as the power of some number greater than 1, which you can get by dividing sequential values.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G(n)$ and $R(n)$ denote the amounts of gold and reputation after $n$ seconds, respectively. Then $G(0)=R(0)=0$ and $R(n)=\lfloor\tfrac{G(n)}{20}\rfloor$ and 
$$G(n+1)=G(n)+10(1+0.1R(n))=G(n)+10(1+0.01\lfloor\tfrac{G(n)}{20}\rfloor).$$
If we ignore the floor function, this becomes $G(n+1)=1.005G(n)+10$, which can be written as
$$\begin{pmatrix}
G(n+1)\\1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1.005&10\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
G(n)\\1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
This gives us an explicit expression for $G(n+1)$ in terms of $n$;
$$\begin{pmatrix}
G(n+1)\\1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1.005&10\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}^{n+1}
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\1
\end{pmatrix}$$
Luckily, powers of this matrix are easy to compute because $\tbinom{0\ 10}{0\ \hphantom{1}0}^2=0$, so by the binomial theorem
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{pmatrix}
1.005&10\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}^{n+1}
&=&\left(
\begin{pmatrix}
1.005&0\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}
+\begin{pmatrix}
0&10\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix}\right)^{n+1}\\
&=&\begin{pmatrix}
1.005&0\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}^{n+1}
+(n+1)\begin{pmatrix}
1.005&0\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}^n
\begin{pmatrix}
0&10\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=&
\begin{pmatrix}
1.005^{n+1}&10(n+1)1.005^n\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}
This shows that
$$\begin{pmatrix}
G(n+1)\\1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1.005^{n+1}&10(n+1)1.005^n\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\1
\end{pmatrix},$$
and hence that
$$G(n+1)=10(n+1)1.005^n.$$
In particular, after $n=1000$ seconds this gives us
$$G(1000)\approx1458464.$$
Keep in mind that we have ignored the floor function at the start; in this model you do not gain $1$ reputation for every $20$ gold in increments, but you simply gain $1/20$-th of your gold in reputation.